# filling in columns with info from other file based on condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, conditional-statements

So there are 2 csv files im working with:
file 1:

```
City     KWR1 KWR2 KWR3

Killeen
Killeen
Houston
Whatever
```

file2:

```
location link                      reviews
Killeen  www.example.com           300
Killeen  www.differentexample.com  200
Killeen  www.example3.com          100
Killeen  www.extraexample.com      20
```

Here's what im trying to make this code do:
look at the 'City' in file one, take the top 3 links in file 2 (you can go ahead and assume the cities wont get mixed up) and then put these top 3 into the KWR1 KWR2 KWR3 columns for all the same 'City' values.

so it gets the top 3 and then just copies them to the right of all the Same 'City' values.

even asking this question correctly is difficult for me, hope i've provided enough information.
i know how to read the file in with pandas and all that, just cant code this exact situation in...

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unusual requirement but I think you need to three steps:
1. Keep only the first three values you actually need.

```
df = df.sort_values(by='reviews',ascending=False).groupby('location').head(3).reset_index()
```

Hopefully this keeps only the first three from every city. 
Then you somehow need to label your data, there might be better ways to do this but here is one way:- You assign a new column with numbers and create a user defined function

```
import numpy as np
df['nums'] = np.arange(len(df))
```

Now you have a column full of numbers (kind of like line numbers)
You create your function then that will label your data...

```
def my_func(index):
    if index % 3  ==0 :
        x = 'KWR' + str(1)
    elif index % 3 == 1:
        x = 'KWR' + str(2)
    elif index % 3 == 2:
        x = 'KWR' + str(3)
    return x
```

You can then create the labels you need:

```
df['labels'] = df.nums.apply(my_func)
```

Then you can do:

```
my_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='reviews', index=['location'], columns='labels', aggfunc='max').reset_index()
```

Which literally pulls out the labels (pivots) and puts the values in to the right places.

Comment: This works perfectly when I'm using just one city, thing is i have a loop which runs this for multiple 'locations' and it keeps overwriting the very first line:
`
City           KWR1     KWR2     KWR3
Killeen      link1         link2        link3
Houston
`
`
Then the loop runs for Houston and gets those links, but:
City          KWR1      KWR2    KWR3
Killeen      link4         link5       link6
Houston
`
so it puts the links for houston in the same spot it put the first links for killeen.

Comment: I doubt you can see the structure i tried to put into that comment :/

basically, can i make the Cities align so that links from Houston never get pasted where it says Killeen?

Comment: what do you mean by having a loop for multiple locations? the first line of the code sorts by the city and keeps the top 3 values... there should be no loops or iterating

Comment: the loop is for a different df. it loops because i run my api multiple times to get the second df (second file) for each city in the first file. the info from the second file simply doesn't arrange itself with the corresponding city. so if the api runs for Houston, the results from it(the links) don't get put next to Houston, but simply in the first place again(overwriting the previous links it gets.)